# Is there a way to password protect the python shell in a Django application?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I want to password protect the shell when running `python manage.py` shell from inside my `Django` app for a `superuser`.

After running `python manage.py` shell I would like to be prompted to enter a superusers username and password.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. The shell is not run for any particular user.

Comment: what is the use case for this? Not sure this could be done in any meaningful sort of way considering someone running the shell also presumably has the code behind it... if you want to prevent certain people from running management commands for some reason, then lock the project files so that only certain OS users can access it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create superusers using the [createsuperuser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#creating-superusers) command:

```
$ python manage.py createsuperuser --username=joe --email=joe@example.com
```

You also can use [django.auth.middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/middleware/). The django.auth.middleware needs to hide some actions for unauth user on your server.

More information about auth in web request [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests)

Comment: the use case would be if the application was running on a local machine used by multiple users, the users would be restricted access to the application data through the site's login and admin login but if they have access to a shel they would have access to the database. The idea would be for someone to set up a superuser account during the installation process (database migrations) and from then on running the shell would require the superuser password

Comment: It looks like you want to use django.auth.miidleware: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/contrib/auth/middleware. Do I right?

Comment: Is it possible for the middleware to activate when running ```python manage.py shell```

Comment: The django.auth.middleware needs to hide some actions for unauth user on your server. The running server on local machine used by multiple untrusted users is not expected. For example django config contains the key. The untrusted user can get access to it too. Why don't you want to use separate machine for this with OS superuser protection?